# Flutter parameters transfering across pages: What about the parameter "key"?

Tags: android, flutter, parameters, flutter-test, flutter-pageview

I have made two pages, PersonalPage and InformationPage. I want to transfer some parameters from PersonalPage to InformationPage. Here are my codes.
PersonalPage:

```
Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Information(phoneNumber: phoneNumber, nickName: nickName, realName: realName, key: key)
          ),
        );
```

InformationPage:

```
class Information extends StatelessWidget {
  String? phoneNumber;
  String? realName;
  String? nickName;
  Information({required Key key, required this.phoneNumber, required this.realName, required this.nickName})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    //Some codes
  }
}
```

In PersonalPage, there is an error in the line including "builder:":

```
Undefined name 'key'.
```

It seems that I need to assign `key`. But I don't know what thing I should put to `key`. So what should I put to `key`？ Or can I just take measures to avoid assigning it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass [Key](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html) as the key field is set required.

```
Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Information(key: Key('keyName'), phoneNumber: phoneNumber, nickName: nickName, realName: realName, key: key)
          ),
        );
```